# Selenium -- How to deal with 2 submit buttons and click on one of them?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation, xpath, regression-testing

The key HTML is:

```
<div class="col col3 actionCol"> 
  <button type="submit" class="booking fRight">Book</button>
</div>
```

but we also have other `form`s on the same page, e.g. for login, that have a similar "submit" button.

How do i click this specific one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you find the element using xpath and specify index within xpath. So for the button you are referring to, the code with indexed xpath would be

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//button[contains(text(),'Book')])[2]"));
```

Alternatively, if you wish to avoid indexes, you may write a more specific xpath to find the element

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='row roundTripHead' and not(contains(@style,'display: none'))]//button"));
```

The above xpath will discard element which has style attribute with value ***display:none***

Comment: This is both hard to read and brittle.  the `not contains @style 'display: none` isn't good for future changes.  It's a valid answer though for those wishing to use xpath and this approach.

Comment: Hi Michael, i was able to use the java script executor and click on the link...awesome..thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can find both of them into an array and find which one you want by using array indexing.

```
buttonArray = webdriver.findElements(submit button xpath / css selector)
firstButton = buttonArray[0]
secondButton = buttonArray[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Be specific enough (but no more) to uniquely select 1 element

### Generally look to css selectors first, for greatest readability.

Try using `button[type='submit']` for your selector and `click` on it, e.g.

`findElement("button[type='submit']").click`

if that is not specific enough, scope it to the `button` or `form` class, examples:

```
button.booking[type='submit']
form button.booking[type='submit']
form.booking button[type='submit']
# Allow form to be put anywhere on the page and other forms to exist
```

If that is not specific enough (the page has two forms with the same name...) you can scope it to the specific occurrence, e.g. for the first occurrence use:

```
form.booking button.booking[type='submit'][0]`  
# However this is now tied to page layout if form order is changed
```

"but no more" in the title generally means don't hard-code a selector using the surrounding page layout.  It may be unique but it then becomes tied the the page layout and breaks if the layout changes.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the index to find the particular element.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[text()='Book'])[1]"));
```